# Windows 7 Language pack appears as installed but doesn't show in list

Tags: windows-7, windows, language

I want to change my Windows 7 Ultimate language to Polish (Currently English).
Windows Update fails installing the language pack (Error Code 8007002).
Attempting to manually install language pack shows me this:

[image: Screenshot]

But the language is not on list to select:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Neither i can uninstall it and reinstall:

[image: Screenshot 3]

I've tried installing other languages and success.

How can I change my system language to Polish?

Comment: Have you tried to download the language pack again?  Have you tried to install any other language pack to see if it will install?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Question Edited.